# How to simulate android back button press programmatically in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have done the same thing in android natively by simply calling `onBackPressed()`.
I've been trying to do the same thing in Unity with c#. there are classes like [Input](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html) that handles inputs but does not have access to android's back button.
I've also seen touch simulators and whatnots but I'm looking for something as simple as calling `this.onBackPressed()`.
Please note that I'm not looking to capture back button press, I want to press back button from my code.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this.

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't want to detect backpress after it happens. I'm looking to invoke pressing back button programmatically, not by user touch.

Comment: You can make an event `event Action OnSimulateBackButtonEvent` then add all necessary listeners back button methods to that event `OnSimulateBackButtonEvent += BackButtonMethod1`.Then when you need to begin the simulation, just invoke the event `OnSimulateBackButtonEvent.Invoke()`

Comment: @Tricko Yup, this could do the trick. tnx